# Facing issue after converting code from JavaScript to CoffeeScript, Code is not working nor displaying any Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
  counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter')
  counters.forEach (counter) ->
  incrementButton = counter.querySelector('.plus')
  decrementButton = counter.querySelector('.minus')
  countElement = counter.querySelector('.count')
  incrementButton.addEventListener 'click', ->
    # Increment the count
    count = parseInt(countElement.textContent, 10)
    count++
    countElement.textContent = count
    return
  decrementButton.addEventListener 'click', ->
    # Decrement the count
    count = parseInt(countElement.textContent, 10)
    if count > 0
      count--
      countElement.textContent = count
    # count--;
    countElement.textContent = count
    return
  return
```

I am using Qunanity Operator for increment and decrement, it is working fine in javascript but after converting it to Coffescript it is not working and not displaying any error in console

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is going on in your code.